# Delete unused ViewController from memory

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have 3 ViewController.
The first ViewController is checking if the user is logged in. 
If yes performSegue to the mainVC and if no performSegue to loginVC.

When I am in loginVC, I log in and performSegue to mainVC.

What I want now is, I want to have all ViewControllers which are unused being "deleted", to save memory.
How is that going to work?

I found here in StackOverflow this piece of code:

```
class ManualSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

  override func perform() {
    sourceViewController.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true) {
      self.sourceViewController.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController = self.destinationViewController
    }
  }
}
```

Is that going to do what I want? It seems like yes because this method is popping the ViewController.

I am using "Show Detail" - segues only, except when using this method I created a custom Segue Segue.

Comment: “Swift uses Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) to track and manage your app’s memory usage. In most cases, this means that memory management “just works” in Swift, and you do not need to think about memory management yourself. ARC automatically frees up the memory used by class instances when those instances are no longer needed.”  Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.0.1).” Apple Inc., 2016-10-21T07:00:00Z. iBooks.  This material may be protected by copyright.  Check out this book on the iBooks Store: https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Answer (score 0):

Deletion should be handled by Apple, you (theoretically) shouldn't have to worry about it, so long as you don't create any retain cycles. As a rule, just don't have any strong references to `self` in blocks. Funny enough, the code you have above, that *should* dismiss the ViewController (and therefore delete it) also has a retain cycle. Adding `[weak self]` and `strongSelf` casts as needed should help:

```
override func perform() {
    sourceViewController.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true) { [weak self] in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        strongSelf.sourceViewController.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController = strongSelf.destinationViewController
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Memory question**

Yes, that is how it works. You do not need to take care of freeing view controllers.

The system will keep track of references to view controller objects. When you do not have references to these anymore then the memory is deallocated. You can read about this more in swift language documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

**What the code is doing**

`presentViewController` method is showing a view controller modally. The completion closure is performed after presenting the new view controller finishes. Inside closer 2 things happen

1. `popToRootViewController`Removes all view controllers inside the `sourceViewController` object.
2. `rootViewController` of the window is set to new value.

This practically changes the root view controller to another one. This seems like a valid action after successful login.

I do not know if step 1 is necessary. That navigation view controller is going to go away anyway so why to pop view controllers inside it?

**More about view controllers**

You might be also interested in view controller life cycle. UIKit developer documentation contains in-depth details about view controllers:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller